# How to limit 1 image per post on homepage only?

Tags: plugins, images, excerpt

most of my post on wordpress got 6 or 5 images perpost. My problem is if I posted 5 new post with new images, it will be totall 25 images display on my homepage.

I want to limit 1 image perpost on "homepage only", the full content (lets say got total 6 images, it will be on single page).

Anyone know how to do it??

Or any Image excerpt plugin that can limit image on homepage?

Answer (score 1):

I use this inside your themes functions.php

```
// function (image toolbox) for all images
 function attachment_toolbox($size = thumbnail) { 

if($images = get_children(array(
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'numberposts'    => 1, // show all images is -1
    'post_status'    => null,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
))) {
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $attimg   = wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID,$size);

        $postlink = get_permalink($image->post_parent);


        echo '<a href="'.$postlink.'">'.$attimg.'</a>';

    }
}
```

}

and call it inside your loop with

```
<div class="around_image"> 
  <?php attachment_toolbox('medium'); ?>
</div><!-- / around_image -->
```

thats straight out of my site im working on right now, change "medium" to the size of the pic you want, "thumbnail", "medium", "large" or "full_size"

for more info [**go here**](http://digwp.com/2009/08/awesome-image-attachment-recipes-for-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @author: wpreceipes
 * @link: [1]: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it
 */
function wpse18215_catch_that_image() 
{
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all( '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches );
    $first_img = $matches[1][0];

    //Defines a default image
    if( empty( $first_img ) )
    { 
        $first_img = '/images/default.jpg';
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

*Example:*

`echo catch_that_image();`

or:

```
/**
 * @author: Marcelo Mesquita
 * @link: http://marcelomesquita.com/
 * @param (string) $size - valid: 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large' or 'full_size'
 * @param (string) $add - any additional attributes for the html-img tag
 */
function wpse18215_the_thumb( $size = 'medium', $add = '' )
{
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $thumb = $wpdb->get_row( 
        "SELECT ID, 
         post_title 
         FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
         WHERE post_parent = {$post->ID} 
         AND post_mime_type 
         LIKE 'image%' 
         ORDER BY menu_order"
    );

    if( ! empty( $thumb ) )
    {
        $image = image_downsize( $thumb->ID, $size );
        return "<img src='{$image[0]}' alt='{$thumb->post_title}' {$add} />";
    }
}
```

*Example:*

`echo wpse18215_the_thumb( 'medium', 'class="alignleft" width="200" height="175"' );`

---

**Note:** You need to wrap the call anyway inside your template into a conditional statement:

`if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { /* place the function call here */ }`

Comment: Thanks alot guys for the very fast replied, its been 2 days googling but I couldn't find what I am looking for, but now I found that answer. Two thumbs up for both of you and also I've bookmarked your site to check whats new on your site. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it worked. You should in any case mark one as the solution :)